# How to query this in raw SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `user` with 2 columns, `name` and `role`. I want to group together for one role all the names which are associated with it.

So suppose for the role "admin" is used by 3 different names.

```
["admin", "john"] 
["admin", "doe"]
["admin", "max"]
```

I want to start my query with this

```
from u is users, where: u.role == "admin"
```

Comment: Start your investigation here https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/how-workaround-oracle-listagg-function-postgresql

Comment: Please add sample data which explain exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: You can use CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT functions of mysql along with GROUP BY if you want to group all names of a role.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added that. What else do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listagg function should help.  need to group the column containing "admin" then it will create a list of the names. basic syntax below.

```
select 
admin_column, 
listagg (name_column, ', ') as names
from wherever 
group by 1;
```